# How can I have different properties and such in a vs 2010 setup project for the for two different release versions?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

What I want is to only have one setup project in my solution, and I want to be able to install 'release1' and the 'release2' versions (as in versions debug/release1/release2) simultaneously on one machine. So, the release1 version needs its own program folder, product code and shortcuts and such, and the release2 version needs its own unique versions of these things too.

It seems however the setup project doesn't store seperate properties for the two different release versions. Seems all thats different is the output path, and of course they use the different generated exes.

Am I going to have to move to Wix to solve this problem? Or is there something simple I'm missing here? It seems kind of stupid that you can't configure the installer to do different things for two different release versions. So far its looking like I'll have to make another setup project, which is going to be annoying because I don't like having to maintain one setup project let alone 2.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Isaac

Comment: Erm, you know that you're not supposed to redistribute the "Debug" version, right? If you just need to be able to debug the program on a remote machine, include the PDB file for the "Release" version.

Comment: yeah, i know. For the purposes of the question, just imagine that I want to have version 'release 1' and version 'release 2'. I know the debug version is not optimized and what not.

Comment: i just figure it's going to be easier to tell my users that if they click on this shortcut here its pointing to the test database, and if they click on this other one over here it points to the real one.

Comment: This is one of those cases where you should consider asking about the original problem, rather than how to implement the "solution" you've settled upon. Why not just create different shortcuts, each pointing to a different database location? Both would start the executable compiled in Release mode, and you won't have to install two separate versions of the software, or try and distribute a Debug version. It's not stupid that the installer doesn't allow you to handle the versions separately. You're explicitly *not supposed to install the Debug version*. Why would they build in support for that?

Comment: Yeah I get it, you shouldn't use the debug version for release.. I'll edit the question to eliminate this confusion. Anyway, no, I really do need to have two different versions installed, because, they might not be the same. After I release this thing this month/next month, they're going to start using it for data entry. And there's some major development left to go on it. So, I need a test version that I can update frequently to get feedback on whether I'm going in the right direction. Meanwhile, the nice stable production version hums along bug free. I guess my situation is not normal.

Comment: @Cody Gray I'm in doubt about your first comment: [Here's the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101458/why-is-a-bad-practice-to-distribute-the-debug-version-of-the-application-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating two different setup projects, one called **Production Setup** and one called **Test Setup** might be the cleanest way, since it makes the OS believe you are delivering two different products, which is in fact the case here.

Moving to WiX, as you suggested by yourself, has indeed the advantage that you can reuse parts in both your setup projects, avoiding the need to maintain the same list of files twice, for example.

There is, of course, another option. If your **Production Setup** and your **Test Setup** projects are almost identical, and you need just to exchange some GUIDs (the product or package code, for example, to make MSI consider them to be different), create a simple script which copies the first setup project file to a second location and exchanges the GUIDs within the file (which is nothing but an XML file). So you have only to maintain the first project file and can regenerate the second one easily by rerunning the script.

Personally I am doing such stuff in VBS, but you can also use powershell for that or write a simple tool in any language capable of doing XML or RegEx processing.

Comment: I'll go with the script. I don't really have the time right now to learn WiX. I'm already editing the msi post build right now with a vbs script anyway, I could just add to that. Hopefully its not too hard to edit the things I want to edit. Thanks for your help!